# w2k3 server - 32 to 64 bit partitions remain?

Tags: windows-server-2003

Currently have a w2k3 server, 32 bit with an OS partition and a 1.7TB data partition, both local raid sets on a dell server. If I delete the 32 bit OS partition and reinstall w2k3 server 64 bit, will the 64 bit install be able to mount and use the 1.7TB data partition that was created and formatted under the 32 bit w2k3 server install ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work just fine.  There are no differences with the format of a drive if done in 32 or 64 bit Windows.